# Dealing with hasMany in rails4 form of two models...select_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

So most examples online show simple 1:1 forms.  I have a form that creates a Group model, fine.  But that Group can have many Providers in it.
(as the model for group has a hasMany: Providers)

So in the form, I list all the text_fields in the group,. I have a submit button etc.

I also have a select_tag that shows all the providers available and sets multiple to true.  What I don't know is how to handle the results?  how to know that when I click save the providers that were selected will get saved.  Is it in the Group controller do I look at the parameter somewhere?  my select tag is thus:

```
        <%= select_tag "organizing_team", options_from_collection_for_select(Provider.all, 'lastname', 'firstname',@group.providers.map{ |j| j.id }), :multiple => true%>
```

The create of my Group Controller is thus:

```
 def create
@group = Group.new(group_params)

respond_to do |format|
    if @group.save
        format.html { redirect_to @group, notice: 'Group was successfully created.'}
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @group }
    else
        format.hmtl { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @group.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
end
```

end

I am kinda thinking I need more code in my create of my Groups controller to deal with what comes back from that form (namely in `group_params.organizing_team` or something close.  Also and maybe easier, in the future...I think I want the create group to handle the standard fields...and to display any providers if there are some, but have the adding/removing of providers from a group in a separate modal like dialog popup.  No clue how I would even do that..such a rails n00b.

So am I on the right track in my thinking?  Handling that whats selected in the select tag in the create controller? (and later also in an edit controller?) and if so... what do I do in that...do I have to go through that map of organizing_team to find out what was selected, somehow look up the @Providers based on the first and last name (I am guessing that's all that comes back...) to find the provider and add it to the group @group.provider = @providerFound ?

(yes pseudocode).

I ask this all because I am assuming the :

```
    @group = Group.new(group_params)
```

Does not magically know how to save the providers that should come back in what I believe to be the hash "organizing_team" (according to my select_tag above?)